# Получение сумм цифр в половинах числа

Tags: java

Например, есть число `1122`, сумма первой половины будет равна `2`, второй - `4`.

Как получить сумму цифр одной половины некоего числа и сумму цифр другой половины?

Число может быть любой длины.

Comment: Если в числе 3 цифры (`123`), то как будут считаться суммы?

Comment: 1. разделить строку на две части; 2. пройтись посимвольно по первой части, конвертируя каждую цифру в числовой тип; 3. просуммировать элементы полученного множества; 4. повторить для второй части. В случае, если строки условно-бесконечны, то действовать итерациями, просто обновляя значения.

Comment: @Equalizer политика stackoverflow такова, что делать всю работу за спрашивающего не принято. Алгоритм вам уже предложили, теперь вы можете написать код самостоятельно. Как появятся вопросы - выкладывайте вместе с кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм 1.

1. запомнили число в переменную
2. завели две переменных для суммирования цифр
3. n = 1
4. Цикл, пока не переберем все разряды

   1. находим остаток от деления числа по модулю 10. Это цифра разряда n
   2. прибавляем остаток к одной из сумм, смотря в какой части числа находимся
   3. делим число на 10 нацело
   4. n++
5. готово.

Алгоритм 2 от @Etki

1. Превращаем число в строку, а строку в массив символов
2. Цикл, пока не переберем весь массив

   1. Очередной символ распознаем в int
   2. прибавляем остаток к одной из сумм, смотря в какой части числа находимся
3. готово

Comment: ох, я даже не увидел, что это число, а не строка

Comment: С числом тоже есть куча вариантов, например, просто пойти с правой стороны, получать остаток от деления на 10, затем делить на десять.

Comment: там с левой, там нужно думать о типах и переполнениях (:

Comment: Ну меня смутила фраза "находим остаток от деления числа по модулю 10n", я так понял, предполагается 12345 делить на 10000 и округлять.